# Duplicated ID in ManageLogin.cshtml built-in template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am using the **built-in template** which comes with ASP.NET MVC 4. The View which is causing problem is: *ManageLogins.cshtml*

This is how the output looks like:

[image]

So, this particular user has connected both Google and Facebook external IDs to his account:

And this is the Built in MS Template which produces the above code (I have changed the appearance a bit, but the code is the same)

```
@foreach (var account in Model.CurrentLogins)
{
    <div class="form-row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveLogin", "Manage"))
        {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div>
            @Html.Hidden("loginProvider", account.LoginProvider)
            @Html.Hidden("providerKey", account.ProviderKey)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Remove" title="Remove this @account.LoginProvider login from your account" />
        </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that this code generates 2 inputs with `id=loginProvider`, and this gives me the browser error:

[image]

How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since model binding occurs on `name` and not `id`, I decided to remove the `id` from the hidden field and just use the `name` attribute:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveLogin", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "inline-form float-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="LoginProvider" value="@Model.LoginProvider" class="d-none login-provider" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ProviderKey" value="@Model" class="d-none provider-key" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Remove" title="Remove this @account.LoginProvider login from your account" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overload of the helper that allows you to provide `htmlAttributes`.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    @Html.Hidden("foo", $"value{i}", new { id = $"foo{i}"})
    ...
}
```

Caveat: while the sample above shows how you can do whatever you want for `name`, `value`, `id`, etc., it *may* affect validation (and force you to customize that too). In your specific use case however, since it's just `id`, it should be fine.